# C++ fill array with objects derived from array type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, polymorphism, derived-class

In C++ I have an array of pointers to Player objects and want to fill it with Fickle objects where Fickle is a class that is derived from Player. This is because I want a general Player array that I can fill with different objects from different classes that all are derived from the Player class.

How can I do this?

I create an array of pointers to Player objects

```
Player ** playerArray;
```

Then initialize the array to a certain size

```
playerArray = new Player *[numPlayersIn];
```

But then the following does not work for some reason:

```
playerArray[i] = new Fickle(0);
```

How can I fill the playerArray with Fickle objects (Fickel is a class derived from Player) ?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I get the error message (in Eclipse IDE):

```
expected ';' before 'Fickle'
```

I think it might be something to do with the definition of Fickle.

The Fickle.hpp file contains:

```
#pragma once
#include "player.hpp";

class Fickle: public Player {
public:
    // constructor
    Fickle(int initChoice){
        choice = initChoice;
    }
}
```

Is this OK or is there a problem with this?

The Player class header file has:

```
class Player {
private:

public:
    int getChoice();
int choice; // whether 0 or 1
virtual void receive(int otherChoice); // virtual means it can be overridden in subclases
};
```

The receive method will be overridden in Fickle and other classes derived from the Player class

UPDATE 2:

OK I think the error is actually due to a different part of the code.

Player defines a method receive:

```
virtual void receive(int otherChoice);
```

That should be overridden by the subclass Fickle but the definition in Fickle:

```
void Fickle::receive(int otherChoice) {}
```

gives the error:

```
no 'void Fickle::receive(int)' member function declared in class 'Fickle'
```

But I don't know why this is because receive is defined in the Player class?

Comment: What error do you get? What is definition of Fickle (first line with the base classes)?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `std::vector`? `std::vector<Player*>` is simple enough. Even better (since you need to manage those pointers) would be [`boost::ptr_vector<Player>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) or `std::vector<shared_ptr<Player>>`.

Comment: What do you mean, "does not work"? As far as the pointer types are concerned it does work, so there must be some error elsewhere in your code. Does `Fickle` have the required constructor? Is `0 <= i < numPlayersIn`?

Comment: Does Fickle derive from *single* Player base (i.e. no multiple inheritance)?

Comment: @ybungalobill: Irrelevant. This idea should work even if there is multiple inheritance.

Comment: @aschepler: Wrong. if the inheritance is not virtual then the cast is ambiguous: there is more than one Player base.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Oh, I thought you meant just multiple inheritance of different classes.  Wasn't thinking about multiple base class subobjects of the same type at all.

Comment: @tree-hacker: That error message suggests the compiler is entirely confused at that point.  The actual error may be on the line before, or maybe you forgot to #include Fickle.hpp in that source file.

Comment: Yes I think the error was coming from somewhere else. I think it's to do with overriding the receive method in the Fickle class but not sure. (See updated question above for details).

Comment: A derived class can choose whether to override each virtual function or not.  If it doesn't, it uses the base class's implementation.  Since you do want to override it, you must put a declaration of the override in class Fickle.  That is, put `virtual void receive(int choice);` in both class Player and class Fickle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you probably should be using a vector instead, there's no real reason a dynamically allocated array *can't* work. Here's a bit of working demo code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Player {
public:
    virtual void show() { std::cout << "Player\n"; }
};

class Fickle : public Player {
public:
    virtual void show() { std::cout << "Fickle\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Player **p = new Player *[2];
    p[0] = new Player;
    p[1] = new Fickle;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        p[i]->show();

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        delete p[i];
    delete [] p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is Player declared as a struct here? Does it make a difference if Player is a class instead of a struct?

Comment: @tree-hacker: it just saves putting in a `public:`. That's the only real difference it makes. To save confusion, I've made both classes with `public:`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot a semicolon at the end of Fickle class:

```
class Fickle: public Player {
    // ...
}; // <---- this semicolon
```

Maybe somewhere else.

UPDATE 2: When you override a virtual function in the derived class you must declare it there too.

Comment: For such a common mistake it's surprisingly hard to track down.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Blame C++ preprocessor. It's especially hard when it comes from the end of some include. When I was a newbie I wasted a hour to track this error once.

Comment: OK I didn't know you had to declare overridden functions in the derived class as well.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not compiling correctly, then you probably didn't `#include` the header that defines `Fickle` in the same source file you have that code. Usually an error like that means the compiler doesn't know what `Fickle` is.

Answer (score 0):

Does `Fickle` have a constructor that accepts an `int` or pointer type? Is it privately derived from `Player`? Otherwise it looks like this should work.

Comment: Yes Fickle does have an int constructor. It is publicly derived from Player I think (see code in question) but am not too sure about derived classes.